# ExtJS 4 working with itemclick function in grid.Panel

Tags: dom, extjs

I'm using

> itemclick: function(grid, record, item, index, e)

in my

> Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {..

I'm googling almost 2 hours and I find more and more ways to select one thing, or do another.Like for example

> console.log(grid.getSelectionModel());

you get something but where I can find all the methods availabale and how to connect one with another to get the effect I want. I just feel lost here and don't know from where to start. I guess it's the ExtJS way to navigate in DOM but is there a place where all the methods are described and what are they used for and after all what's the way to navigate through all this - just smoe standart JavaScript that I've missed or something ExtJS specific ...

Thanks

Leron

Comment: What's your question exactly? Where can you find documentation? I think Sencha's own documentation is pretty full and well done. They also have bunch of samples and guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you found this by now, but the API doc are [**here**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/). Each of the ExtJS objects are listed under the tab with a gear looking icon. Clicking on one will open a tab for that object with all of its config options, properties and methods.

Comment: Yeah I use the API since I deal with ExtJS but I find it very confusing compaired to others.I'm not a pro in say - jQuery but for example there is a lot more easier to find certain element and add events to it, and in ExtJS that is what troubles me more - adding the events and configuring the handler fnctns so I thought that maybe I miss something that could make the things more clear for me.